# R padding datetime data by groups based on another datetime variable

Tags: r, datetime, data.table, grouping, padding

I have a data table with POSIXct datetime (t1) data which is grouped by multiple columns. My data should have 48 rows at half hourly intervals (24 hrs total) for each group, whose datetime (t1) value is determined by another datetime (t2) variable used as part of the grouping variables. The 48 rows of (t1) data should be 24 hours of half hourly intervals leading up to the grouped datetime (t2).

I need the missing rows to be populated with the values from the **previous (chronologically) complete row of data** for each group.

For example: If the data grouped by ID = A, datetime (t2) = **10-01-2019 06:00:00** (format = 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss') has datetime (t1) data that spans from **09-01-2019 08:00:00** until **10-01-2019 04:00:00**. It should span from **09-01-2019 06:00:00** until **10-01-2019 05:30:00**, meaning 4 rows of data (2 hrs) are missing from the beginning, 3 rows of data are missing from the end, and several rows are missing in between the available data points as well.  While rows missing at the start of the time period cannot be filled in with complete data, I would still like the rows to be added to the table as NA.  However it is very important for the rows at the end of the table to be populated with complete data from the previous complete row of data.

An example of my dataset is shown below: (grouped by ID and t2)

```
ID t2                   t1                    varX   varY
... 
A  10-01-2019 06:00:00  10-01-2019 12:00:00   100    Y1 
A  10-01-2019 06:00:00  10-01-2019 12:30:00   60     Y2 
B  10-01-2019 06:00:00  10-01-2019 01:00:00   100    Y2 
A  10-01-2019 06:30:00  10-01-2019 01:30:00   100    Y3 
B  10-01-2019 06:30:00  10-01-2019 02:00:00   200    Y4  
C  10-01-2019 07:00:00  10-01-2019 04:00:00   100    Y3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear if the time is in 24hr format. You can first create a sequence of half-hourly timings, then join with the original dataset before using `zoo::na.locf` to carry the last observation forward:

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("ID,t2,t1,varX,varY
A,10-01-2019 06:00:00 PM,10-01-2019 12:00:00 PM,100,Y1 
A,10-01-2019 06:00:00 PM,10-01-2019 12:30:00 PM,60,Y2 
B,10-01-2019 06:00:00 PM,10-01-2019 01:00:00 PM,100,Y2 
A,10-01-2019 06:30:00 PM,10-01-2019 01:30:00 PM,100,Y3 
B,10-01-2019 06:30:00 PM,10-01-2019 02:00:00 PM,200,Y4 
C,10-01-2019 07:00:00 PM,10-01-2019 04:00:00 PM,100,Y3") 
cols <- c("t2", "t1")
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct, format="%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), .SDcols=cols]
```

code:

```
library(zoo)
DT[DT[,.(t1=rev(seq(t2-30*60, length.out=48L, by="-30 mins"))), by=.(ID, t2)],
    .(ID=i.ID, t2=i.t2, t1=i.t1, varX=varX, varY=varY),
    on=.(ID, t2, t1)][,
        c("varX", "varY") := lapply(.SD, na.locf, na.rm=FALSE),
        , by=.(ID, t2), .SDcols=c("varX", "varY")][]
```

Comment: The grouping variables for my data are actually ID and t2 together.  When I tried your code with slightly different data that includes different values of t2, and updated the the data table to be "by = .(ID, t2)", it returned the expected number of rows, the correct values for t1, but the values of t2 were incorrect: they were all the same as the first value of t2.

Comment: Using the data:
DT <- fread("ID,t2,t1,varX,varY
A,10-01-2019 06:00:00 PM,10-01-2019 12:00:00 PM,100,Y1 
A,10-01-2019 06:00:00 PM,10-01-2019 12:30:00 PM,60,Y2 
B,10-01-2019 06:00:00 PM,10-01-2019 01:00:00 PM,100,Y2 
A,10-01-2019 06:30:00 PM,10-01-2019 01:30:00 PM,100,Y3 
B,10-01-2019 06:30:00 PM,10-01-2019 02:00:00 PM,200,Y4
C,10-01-2019 07:00:00 PM,10-01-2019 04:00:00 PM,100,Y3")
It should return 240 rows with the three different t2 times across the whole table, but there's only the first time 10-01-2019 06:00:00 PM for every value in the t2 column (following conversion to POSIXct)

Comment: I adjusted the code to be: DT[
  DT[,.(t1=rev(seq(t2[1L]-30*60, length.out=48L, by="-30 mins"))), 
     by=.(ID,t2)],
  .(ID=i.ID, t2=i.t2, t1=i.t1, 
    varX=na.locf(varX, na.rm=FALSE), varY=na.locf(varY, na.rm=FALSE)),
  on=.(ID, t2, t1)]   But values for varX and varY are being carried down into the next group, instead of the next group starting with NA values until the first complete row of data appears for that group.

Comment: @Michael96 I updated the code with the new sample dataset. you might want to post this sample dataset in the OP as it is clearer